# Multihread communication between two services in java Apache CXF (SOAP)

Tags: java, spring, web-services, cxf, message-queue

I have two services hosted under the same context file in Spring + Apache CXF (Services **A** and **B**). There is a third-party service C, that I have to call from service A, and that will send the response to service **B**. (by means of addressing). I have managed to perform the communication between services **A -> C -> B**. Everything OK there. The problem is I would like to perform some logic in service **A** according to the response sent to service **B**. That means I would like to do something like this in service **A**

```
ServiceC_Client clientC = ....
....
clientC.callOperation();
// somehow wait for a signal from service B or until a timeout have been reached. 
// The response will be correlated to this particular thread by means of 
// WS-Addressing MessageId field
// Read relevant data response sent to B (B stores the relevant data in database)
....
// continue operation of method of A
```

In service **B**, I would have something like this

```
public void callBackResponse(ResponseData response){
    // Perform operations with response and store relevant data in database
    // Service A will know data is sent to a particular run of A thanks to 
    // Addressing MessageID and RelatesTo fields

    // Notify Service A a response was received
}
```

Is this possible? Can I achieve this in Java? Maybe Java Message Queues? I don't really know if it is possible.

Comment: Create a restful API in Service A and invoke it from Service B.

Comment: All three services are SOAP

Comment: you should use apache camel route engine to redirect and process request/response.

Comment: Could you point me to a direction where I could find out information about this specific case scenario using apache Camel?